# Does typescript webpack require a webpack.config.ts file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I've looked everywhere for any documentation that can definitively tell me this, but I can't find an answer.

I'm using webpack and typescript, and I've just transitioned from using a `webpack.config.ts` file to a `webpack.prod.ts` and a `webpack.dev.ts` file.

I'm using the `--config webpack.prod.ts` and `--config webpack.dev.ts` flags in my package.json scripts.

The thing is that they won't run when I call them, my primary error is that my aliases won't resolve.

What's weird is that as soon as I add in an empty `webpack.config.ts` file, everything runs an compiles correctly.

This is what makes me wonder about whether or not it needs to exist, or if there is a package in the setup that expects that file to be there, like does `ts-node` rely on that file existing.

I can't see anything in the webpack typescript docs https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-languages/#typescript that say that it needs to have that file, but you would expect that would be pretty important information to have.

I'm currently using `"webpack": "^4.46.0"` and `"ts-node": "^9.1.1"` but I'm basically guessing at that being the cause.

Comment: It's worth noting that I added a console.log to my `webpack.config.js` and it logs twice if I use it as my config path, and it also logs when I give webpack a completely different `--config` file. So it is definitely automatically being called despite providing a different config file in the webpack command :(